# Multiply 2 elements in each row, create new column, list of lists - python

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list of lists:

```
mylist = [['Bob','AA',3,2.1,4],['Sally','BB',2,5.1,3],['Jim','CC',2,1.5,4]]
```

I need to multiply elements 2 and 3 and insert the resulting solution to index 4, shifting everything over and format the float errors.  Desired output:

```
mylist = [['Bob','AA',3,2.1,6.3,4],['Sally','BB',2,5.1,10.2,3],['Jim','CC',2,1.5,3,4]]
```

I have almost solved this with:

```
for i, val in enumerate(mylist):
    sol = (float(val[2]*val[3]))
    val.insert(4,'%.3f' % sol)

print(mylist)
```

I'm getting:

```
[['Bob', 'AA', 3, 2.1, 6.300, 4], ['Sally', 'BB', 2, 5.1, 10.200, 3], ['Jim', 'CC', 2, 1.5, 3.000, 4]]
```

2 questions:

1. Is there a more pythonic way than my current solution? (list comprehension would be nice)
2. How do I correctly format the float errors? (EDIT: Included '%.3f' % at the insert, seems to work ok.)

Comment: You don't "format" float errors. You could, of course, use `round`, or you just accept the values as they are (better for calculations). Also: unfortunately, there are no list comprehensions for `insert`...

Comment: You should use the new format string syntax (`"{:.3f}".format(sol)`) instead of the old *printf* syntax (`"%.3f" % sol`)...

Comment: @hlt: If you're just formatting a single value, use the `format` function: `format(sol, '.3f')`; don't create and fill in a `str.format` template with just one thing in it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more pythonic way than my current solution? (list comprehension would be nice)

A list comprehension is a Pythonic way to build a list. It is not a Pythonic way to apply side effects to a bunch of values. The Pythonic way to do that is to use a `for` statement, exactly as you've done.

There's nothing really wrong with your code, but, like most code, it can be improved:

- Don't use `enumerate` if you don't need the `i` value; just loop over the list itself.
- Don't convert values to `float` that are guaranteed to already be `float` values.
- Don't put extra parens around an entire expression unless they're somehow useful for readability.
- For formatting a single value, the `format` function is usually simpler and more readable (and maybe more efficient, but that's unlikely to matter) than either `str.format` or `%`.
- Identifiers should use complete English words, except for standard technical abbreviations, when feasible.
- When multiplying two compound expressions, it's arguably clearer with spaces around the
  `*` (although `value[2]` is on the borderline here).

So:

```
for value in mylist:
    solution = value[2] * value[3]
    value.insert(4, format(solution, '.3'))
```

[PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) provides a little guidance on a few of these issues, but not much.

---

Meanwhile, presumably those elements have some inherent meaning. I don't know what they represent, but it might be better to unpack them into named variables instead of just using the indices:

```
    name, thingy, count, weight, stuffness = value
    solution = count * weight
```

Or:

```
    _, _, count, weight, _ = value
    solution = count * weight
```

---

Also, given that these things are fixed-shape, heterogeneous collections, it might be better to store them as tuples rather than lists. Of course what you're doing is mutating the list, so that doesn't apply here. But maybe you shouldn't be doing this mutably in the first place. Maybe it would be better to build a new list of new tuples. In which case you actually *could* use a list comprehension:

```
[value + (format(value[2] * value[3], '.3'),) for value in mylist]
```

… or, combining the last two ideas:

```
[(name, thingy, count, weight, stuffness, format(count * weight, '.3'))
 for (name, thingy, count, weight, stiffness) in mylist]
```

Whether that's actually more readable or more pythonic is pretty arguable.

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Is there a more pythonic way than my current solution? (list comprehension would be nice)

Your approach to use `for` loop is correct and very "pythonic." Just a small note here:

- You don't have to use `enumerate()` if you aren't using the index `i` in your code

That said, you can also use list comprehension here if you are interested in considering other python-specific alternatives. There are two ways of doing so:

**List-Comprehension using operator overloading:**

You can also use the list concatenation by overloading the `+` operator. The solution would be more elegant if you relax your condition that the new product would go into the 4th index, and instead place the output at the end of the list. Thus, we can replace the for-loop with just one list comprehension:

```
myList = [ val + [float( format( val[2]*val[3], '.3f'))] for val in myList ]
```

This will give us:

```
>>> print(myList)
[['Bob', 'AA', 3, 2.1, 4, 6.3], ['Sally', 'BB', 2, 5.1, 3, 10.2], ['Jim', 'CC', 2, 1.5, 4, 3.0]]
```

You can still achieve your desired output of placing the product into the 4th index using a little less-elegant formulation:

```
myList = [ val[:3] + [float( format( val[2]*val[3], '.3f'))] + val[4:] for val in myList ]
```

**List-Comprehension with `insert()`:**

`insert()` function works a little differently, so be cautious about it. `insert()`, when used inside a list comprehension, modifies the original list. Thus, you don't need to assign the list comprehension to a new variable.

With this in mind, you can replace the for-loop with:

```
[ val.insert( 4, float( format( val[2] * val[3], '.3f') ) for val in myList ];
```

This will correctly update your `myList` variable, giving us as before:

```
>>> print(myList)
[['Bob', 'AA', 3, 2.1, 6.3, 4], ['Sally', 'BB', 2, 5.1, 10.2, 3], ['Jim', 'CC', 2, 1.5, 3.0, 4]]
```

**Notes on using list-comprehension with `insert()` function:**

1. Semicolon, `;`, at the end of the list comprehension is required to suppress the unnecessary output, which would otherwise result in `[None, None, None]` being displayed.
2. Usage of list comprehension, however, may not be recommended in this case as it makes the solution less readable, and wastes memory resources by building a list that is never used.

> ```
> 2. How do I correctly format the float errors? (EDIT: Included '%.3f' % at the insert, seems to work ok.)
> ```

As you can see above, `format()` function works best here.

**Notes on floating point precision:**

1. Using the `format()` function allocates the proper floating point precision to the number, and Casting the result string to a `float()` afterwards appropriately strips off the trailing extraneous zeros.
2. Since you are evaluating a product here, you don't need to cast one of the elements or the product itself as `float()`, because you don't loose any precision during multiplication. However, casting is essential if you were to divide 2 of the list elements. In that case, either the divisor or the dividend must first be cast as `float( val[2] )` to ensure floating point division, otherwise it will result in an integer division.

Comment: Using a list-comp for its side effects is not recommended... you're still building a list, you're just happening to ignore the result - not exactly good use of memory resource and relies on someone reading the code to understand the list-comp is being mis-used and has no meaningful return value...

Comment: you have a point about memory resource usage because of the creation of the list. However, the question specifically asked for an "alternative" way of achieving the same result that is also specific to "python." Nevertheless, I have incorporated your comment in my answer by including a note about efficiency.